# Proof about scalar multiplication of this norm

Tags: proof-verification, normed-spaces

Let $V$ be a normed vector space and $W$ a closed subspace of $V$. It is possible to define a norm on $V/W$ (the quotient space) by defining $\|v + W \| = \inf_{w \in W} \|v + w\|$. As an exercise I tried to prove that for $c \in \mathbb C$:
$$ |c| \|v + W \| = \|cv + W \|$$

But I'm not sure my proof is right. Could anyone please check my proof?

Proof: The claim is clearly true if $c=0$. If $c \neq 0$ then $cW = W$ and therefore
$$ |c| \|v + W \| = |c| \inf_{w \in W} \|v+w\| = \inf_{w \in W} \|cv+cw\| = \inf_{w \in cW} \|cv+w\| = \|cv + W\|$$

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Me too. For this sort of proof, I find it helpful to distinguish the various norms involved (for example, $\|\cdot\|_V$, $\|\cdot\|_{V/W}$).